# PHP How to pass all array's values as different arguments to a function?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array like this

```
$update = array(
  'field1' => 'one',
  'field2' => 'two',
  'field3' => 'three'
);
```

Then I have a function, let's say `write()` which accepts unlimited number of arguments like this `write($thing_one,$thing_two,$thing_three,$thing_four)`

So I know I can pass arguments like `write($update[0],$update[1],$update[2])` but in real example I have a lot of keys and values in `$update` and what I want to do is find a way to pass arguments from this array to a function, so that it would be same as manually typing `update($update[0],$update[1],$update[2])`

I hope somebody will help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Why not pass the whole array?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are getting confused partly because of the way you set up your applications logic. This really shouldn't be an issue as people would usually just assemble an array of parameters to pass as a whole. I suggest you reconsider your logic here (or alternatively explain it abit more so that we can give suggestions)

Comment: just set your `write()` function to receive one variable and then retrieve individually inside the function by means of an index

Comment: write does not accept an array. It accepts many arguments. To better understand this it is coming from mysqli class.

example: $dbi->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`,`surname`) VALUES (?,?);")->execute('john','davids');

So I can create (`name`,`surname`) from array, and (?,?) as well, but cannot create 'john','davids' as arguments for execute function.

thanks

Comment: pass whole array values by using foreach....

Comment: your problem is solve or still need solution.i think foreach will solve your problems using increment counter.

Comment: Sovled. Thanks. call_user_func_array(array($obj,"func"),$args) does a job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) should do the trick nicely.

Comment: This does job. Thanks. $stmt = $this->dbi->prepare($sql);
  $stmt = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "execute"), $args);

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the array itself to the write function:

```
$update = array(
  'field1' => 'one',
  'field2' => 'two',
  'field3' => 'three'
);

write($update);
```

Comment: since when php is type safe?

Comment: yes write does not accept an array. It accepts many arguments. To better understand this it is coming from mysqli class.

example: $dbi->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`name`,`surname`) VALUES (?,?);")->execute('john','davids');

So I can create (`name`,`surname`) from array, and (?,?) as well, but cannot create 'john','davids' as arguments for execute function.

thanks

Comment: @ftom2 Try passing an array to `echo`. By your logic it should be the same as passing the individual values.

Comment: @Kolink - I am assuming `write()` is a function he wrote, not a built in function, and as he mentioned it accepts many arguments, so it seems better to just send an array and if needed change the functionality a bit to accommodate to it.

Comment: That's how I managed to do this: $stmt = $this->dbi->prepare($sql);
  $stmt = call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "execute"), $args);